# how to get product alert email outside magento

Tags: email, email-reminders

I want to send the product stock alert mail from outside magento app folder.

How will i access the email object for that outside magento?

I have already bootstrapped Mage.php file

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$templateId = 'product_stock_alert';

$emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadByCode($templateId);
//$vars = array('user_name' => $userName, 'product_name' => $productName);
//$emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($vars);
$emailTemplate->setSenderEmail(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email', $storeId));

$emailTemplate->setSenderName(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name', $storeId));

    foreach ($emails as $email) {
        if (in_array($email['product_id'], $qty)) {
            $emailTemplate->send($email['email_id'],'Alvaro');
        }
    }
```

EDIT:Any clue at least where to start checking on this?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below....
`Mage::getModel('productalert/observer')->process();` is used for stock /price alert mail.
If you want to only send product stock alert then use

Goto  to `app/code/core/Mage/ProductAlert/Model/Observer.php` make  processStock type `protected to public.`..After that

```
$email = Mage::getModel('productalert/email');
Mage::getModel('productalert/observer')->_processStock($email);
```

See more it code goes to `app/code/core/Mage/ProductAlert/Model/Observer.php`